# Informix : For loop

Tags: string, parsing, loops, for-loop, informix

I have to write a stored proc which will take in the comma delimited string of movie ids, and will get me a list of movie names from the dB. I have tried, but I am not sure if the syntax is correct, obviously db Vis is throwing syntax error

Pl.Help.

```
  Code:

CREATE PROCEDURE test_sp() returning VARCHAR(255);
begin


define set_movieIds, t_movieNames varchar(255);
define t_movieID varchar(5);
define t_count, t_length integer;


let set_movieIds = '54565' ||',' || '55258' || ',' || '55711' || ',' ||'52719' || ',';
let t_length = length(set_movieIds);

for t_count IN (0 TO t_length) loop
        IF(set_movieIds[t_count] is not ',')
                THEN

                 for t_count in (t_count to t_count+4)
                     let t_movieID[t_count] = set_movieIds[t_count]
                 end for;

                select movie_name into t_movieNames 
                from tbl_cinemasource_movieinfo 
                where movie_id = t_movieID      
                let t_movieNames = t_movieNames || ',';

        end if;


exit when t_count = t_length;
end loop;


return t_movieNames;
end;
END PROCEDURE;
```

Answer (score 4):

There are a variety of issues here.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE test_sp() returning VARCHAR(255);

    begin
```

This `BEGIN` is not concretely wrong, but it is aconventional and unnecessary.

```
    define set_movieIds, t_movieNames varchar(255);
    define t_movieID varchar(5);
    define t_count, t_length integer;

    let set_movieIds = '54565' ||',' || '55258' || ',' || '55711' || ',' ||'52719' || ',';
```

Why not just a simple literal?  And why a trailing comma? However, those are cosmetic, not functional issues.

```
    let t_length = length(set_movieIds);

    for t_count IN (0 TO t_length) loop
```

This is not a supported notation in Informix SPL (stored procedure language).  You'd write a more conventional loop as:

```
    FOR t_count = 0 TO t_length
```

Continuing...

```
        IF (set_movieIds[t_count] is not ',') THEN
```

`IS NOT` pretty much has to be followed by `NULL` (though Standard SQL would allow `TRUE`, `FALSE` or `UNKNOWN` too).  But you are looking for a 'not equals' operator anyway. The parentheses are optional.

```
        IF set_movieIds[t_count] != ',' THEN
```

---

Addition: One of the less satisfactory features of SPL is that string subscripts written using the subscript notation can only have constant integers as subscripts. Fortunately, there's a way around the problem, using the SUBSTR() function instead:

```
        IF SUBSTR(set_movieIds, t_count, 1) != ',' THEN
```

---

Continuing...

```
             for t_count in (t_count to t_count+4)
```

Syntactically, that should be:

```
             FOR t_count = t_count TO t_count+4
```

Semantically, that gives me a headache.  You need an extra variable for this inner loop;

```
             FOR u_count = t_count TO t_count+4
```

Continuing...

```
                 let t_movieID[t_count] = set_movieIds[t_count]
             end for;
```

I'm not clear what you are trying to copy. I think you might need a variable starting at 1 (I'll call it `v_count`) and the `u_count` and then:

```
                 LET t_movieID[v_count] = set_movieIds[u_count];
                 LET v_count = v_count + 1;
```

*[This will need adjusting too.]*

You might be OK without the semi-colon after the LET, you might not.  The inconsistency there drives me bonkers.

Continuing...

```
            select movie_name into t_movieNames 
            from tbl_cinemasource_movieinfo 
            where movie_id = t_movieID
```

You'll need a semi-colon after the SELECT statement.

```
            let t_movieNames = t_movieNames || ',';

        end if;

    exit when t_count = t_length;
```

This notation is not part of SPL.  You'd have to write:

```
    IF t_count = LENGTH THEN EXIT FOR; END IF;
```

(You might not need both those semi-colons.)  OTOH, you are also about to go into the next cycle of the FOR loop.  With the introduction of `u_count` above, you may need to adjust `t_count`.

```
    end loop;
```

You must write END FOR to end a FOR loop; you write END IF to end an IF statement; you write END XYZ to end an XYZ construct.  That much at least is consistent.

```
    return t_movieNames;
    end;

END PROCEDURE;
```

So much for the dissection of what is there.  With that said, it feels really uncomfortable.  I'd normally expect to write a cursory procedure that would return each movie title as a separate result.  I'd also be looking to use something other than a string to describe the movies to be selected.  Since the list is hard-coded here, I'd modify the SELECT statement to use an IN list.  If the list is variable, I'd use a temporary table populated with the movie IDs that I'm after.  That would be created outside this procedure.  Alternatively, assuming you are using a current (supported) version of Informix Dynamic Server (rather than say IDS 7.x or OnLine 5.20), then you could use a SET of integers (or VARCHAR(5)) values to describe the list of movies.

Thus, in the simplest case, I'd have:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE test_sp() RETURNING VARCHAR(255) AS movieName;

    DEFINE t_movieNames varchar(255);

    FOREACH SELECT movie_name
              INTO t_movieNames 
              FROM tbl_cinemasource_movieinfo 
             WHERE movie_id IN (54565, 55258, 55711, 52719)
        RETURN t_movieNames WITH RESUME;
    END FOREACH;

END PROCEDURE;
```